# Words or phrases which reflect gender stereotype about driving

Tags: single-word-request, phrase-request

In general, the prejudice that women can't drive well is common. Are there single words or phrases belittling female drivers in Korean?

Comment: Are there such words in other languages, just for example? In the three other languages I know, all from different language families, there isn't any such word. I'm guessing Korean doesn't have such a word as well.

Comment: @busukxuan I'm afraid in Britain, simply saying "women drivers" or "woman drivers" has a negative connotation!

Comment: @topomorto I wasn't aware, but I'm not surprised either. I would't call it a special word or phrase, IMHO it's just using the word "woman" in a context where emphasis on gender can imply sexist connotations.

Comment: @busukxuan yes - I'd be interested in learning a more special one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is '김여사' which translates into 'Madame Kim'. It's a derogatory term for bad female driver.

Kim is the most common last name in Korea and '여사' is a formal title often used for someone with higher education or wealth.

Basically, stereotyping upper class people who have chauffeurs,  or who get their driver's license via bribery, etc. that don't know how to drive.

[wikipedia entry](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%EC%9D%98_%EC%9D%B8%ED%84%B0%EB%84%B7_%EC%8B%A0%EC%A1%B0%EC%96%B4_%EB%AA%A9%EB%A1%9D)

Here's an example of video post with the term used in the title

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_15grlY8UA

Google for more examples.

Comment: It's a slang used by Koreans. Any video of bad driving in Korea would have title and comments section filled with reference to 김여사. Actually, I don't know where else this term would be considered derogatory other than when referring to bad driving.

Comment: Please include the link in your answer. I upvote your answer.

Comment: re-read your comment and fixed it

Comment: Great. It would be even better if you could include the link that explains the word such as this. [김여사:「명사」사장의 부인이 자가용을 끌고다닌다는 데에서 유래한 김여사는 운전을 못하는 여성을 광범위하게 지칭하는 말로 발전했다. 여성 운전자가 도로에서 쩔쩔매거나, 황당한 사고를 냈을 때 '김여사'라는 호칭을 쓴다.](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD%EC%9D%98_%EC%9D%B8%ED%84%B0%EB%84%B7_%EC%8B%A0%EC%A1%B0%EC%96%B4_%EB%AA%A9%EB%A1%9D).

Comment: lol that's a great list

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a particular word to describe a woman who can't drive well. However, you can hear people say

> 왜 너는 아줌마처럼 (아줌마같이) 운전하냐? Why are you driving like a middle-aged woman?

(1) when you are sitting too close to the wheel, (2) you can't overtake other cars very well, (3) when you don't park your car nicely, etc.

'[아줌마](http://krdic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=%EC%95%84%EC%A4%8C%EB%A7%88&kind=all)' is a disrespectful word for '아주머니' and it is used in a variety of context to be scornful or sarcastic when people show an unbecoming behavior or appearance.

Comment: @topomorto which sounds a lot like the example you gave, but even worse: it even includes age